# Smooth grabbing

Tags: javascript, user-interface, acceleration

I've made a simple [grabbing demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/NV/Nkf9n/). It doesn't have any easing/acceleration. I would like to do the same easing/acceleration as on [kulesh.info](http://kulesh.info/) (Flash website) using JavaScript. How can I do that?

Any examples of smooth grabbing (scrolling, dragging) in JavaScript would be helpful as well as a language agnostic algorithm.

Comment: `kulesh.info` is loading too slowly to be of any use; do you have another link with a similar effect?

Comment: Typical flash site.  It's hardly even navigable... decent effect though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the flash look by using an easing equation sometimes referred to as zeno's paradox.

```
position += (destination - position) / damping
```

I modified your jsFiddle to make use of it: [Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkf9n/18/)

If you'd like me to give a more detailed description of zeno's paradox, let me know and I'll post one here with an image or two.

Comment: Interesting approach, but non-WebKit browsers have noticeable lag when grabbing starts. Doesn't work in Firefox, because you haven't specified second argument.

Comment: interesting ... haven't specified a second argument for what?

Comment: ah i see... second argument of the setInterval function. I've updated my link to include that - was just a simple typo ... I normally include that argument.

Comment: which non-Webkit browser or browsers did you test it in?

Comment: Firefox 3.6, Opera 10.63, IE8.

Comment: @st3 - It adds easing but I wouldn't say it's faster: http://jsbin.com/ageci3/14/

Answer (score 8):

I think this is the best you can get with jQuery: **[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ageci3/26/)]**

```
jQuery.fx.interval = 1; // since v1.4.3
var photos = $(".photos");
var scrollLeft = photos[0].scrollLeft;
var $el = $(photos[0]);
var lastTime = +new Date();


$(window).mousemove(function(event){
    var now = +new Date();
    var elapsed = now - lastTime;
    if (dragging && elapsed > 10) {
        scrollLeft += x - event.clientX;
        $el.stop().animate({scrollLeft:  scrollLeft}, 300, "easeOutCubic");
        x = event.clientX;
        lastTime = +new Date();
    }
});

$(window).mouseup(function(event){
    dragging = false;
    $el.stop().animate({scrollLeft:  scrollLeft}, 500, "easeOutCubic");
});
```

*Note, all the possible (slight) sluggishness can't be corrected at the moment, because it's related to image rendering performance of modern browsers. [Test](http://jsbin.com/ageci3/9/) - simple linear animation, no events, no jQuery*

Comment: Seems to be the best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
photos[0].scrollLeft += x - event.clientX;
```

with this ([Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Nkf9n/1/)):

```
photos.animate({ scrollLeft : '+=' + (x - event.clientX) }, 12, 'easeOutCirc');
```

Note that I clicked on jQuery UI to include the easing options. Also, it is very jumpy in the jFiddle (using Firefox) demo, but it doesn't do that at all when I test it on my desktop or if I look at that demo in Chrome. Ideally using the easing function without using jQuery animate would be best. But this should give you an idea.

Comment: 12ms delay is too small to do any significant change. I almost don't see any difference in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox 4 beta. I've tried to use throttling http://jsfiddle.net/NV/Nkf9n/3/, but it's still much worse comparing to the Flash version.

Comment: Well, I messed around with the animation timing and anything greater than 20ms was too much and less than 10ms was too little. It's all really dependent on the browser... I can't think of anything else to do =(... but you might want to consider adding mouse wheel scrolling - I made this demo a while back as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var dragging = false;
var x, startX, startTime, stopTime;
var photos = $(".photos");

photos.mousedown(function(event){
    dragging = true;
    startX = x = event.clientX;
    startTime = new Date();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$(window).mousemove(function(event){
    if (dragging) {
        photos[0].scrollLeft += x - event.clientX;
        stopTime = new Date();
        x = event.clientX;
    }
});

$(window).mouseup(function(event){
    dragging = false;
    var left = photos[0].scrollLeft;
    var dx = (startX - event.clientX);
    var time = stopTime - startTime;
    var speed =time/dx;
    photos.animate({ scrollLeft : (left + dx*time/500), easing :'swing' }, 100/time*1000);  
});
```

Comment: It adds animation on mouse up, but doesn't change an acceleration while I'm grabbing an image.